# Monaco-Editor: Adding Typescript Type Declarations not working

Tags: typescript, types, declaration, monaco-editor

I try to add Typescript Type declarations afterwards.
However, the editor does not take this over. What am I doing wrong?
I also tried it later, when the editor is already loaded.

As example:

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';

...

constructor() {
   monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib("export declare var blub: any;");
}
```

Comment: Okay, I removed the "export" from string and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I removed the "export" from string and it works.